# Angular how to use generated bearer token on page load?

Tags: angular, backend

Inside my categoriescomponent file:

```
  export class CategoriesComponent implements OnInit {
 
  constructor(private categoryService: CategoryService, private loginService: LoginService) { }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loginService.loginServer().subscribe(
      data => console.log(data)
    );
  }
}
```

Inside my login.service.ts file:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginService {
  url = 'http://localhost:3030/api/auth/login';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
  }

  loginServer(){
    return this.http.post(this.url, {"username": "testadmin", "password": "123456"})
  }
}
```

On page load I want to generate a bearer token and make auto login or I'd like to assign it to a method. But I can only log the token on console. I can't send http header with generated token. How to manage it?

Comment: Http Interceptor worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Create Http Interceptor

Notes ( replace `this.jwt.token;` with your jwt variable )

`JwtService` is just global service contain jwt string variable

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    activeRequests: number = 0;

    constructor(private jwt: JwtService) { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        let headers: { [key: string]: string } = {};

        let token: string = this.jwt.token;
        if (token) {
            headers['Bearer-Token'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
        }
        req = req.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                ...headers
            }
        });
      
        return next.handle(req);
    }


}
```

and in app module provider
add this

```
 { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JwtInterceptor, multi: true },
```

Comment: On the constructor I didn't understand the JwtService. I get error can not find name JwtService

Comment: I think @Shifty is referring to your `LoginService` when mentioning `JwtService` in his code

Comment: @Shifty JwtService just where you saved your token replace it with your jwt place , i will edit anwser